# Unable to Compare JSON object values(same object values, from0 to n)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have one JSON object and contains list of currency values. If all currencies are not same I need to do a validation like "data mismatched", all same currencies need to proceed the remaining validations(else part). I tried with below code but failing at comparison.

```
Ex: 

'[{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"USD"}]';  // data mismatches

'[{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"EUR"}]';  // data matches

'[{"currency":"USD"},{"currency":"INR"},{"currency":"EUR"}]';  // data mismatches
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var text = '[{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"USD"}]';
obj = JSON.parse(text);
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[0].currency != obj[i].currency) {
        alert("Data mismatched");
    } else {
        alert("Data matched");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `data.every(({currency}) => currency === data[0].currency)`.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can use the `every()` method to ensure that all `currency` properties in the objects are the same:

```js
let checkCurrencies = (arr) => arr.every(item => item.currency === arr[0].currency);

let invalidArr = JSON.parse('[{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"USD"}]');
console.log(checkCurrencies(invalidArr)); // = false

let validArr = JSON.parse('[{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"EUR"}]');
console.log(checkCurrencies(validArr)); // = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Just revise a little bit in your for loop, here is the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var text = '[{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"EUR"},{"currency":"USD"}]';
obj = JSON.parse(text);
var isDataMismatch = false;
var first = obj[0].currency;
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (first != obj[i].currency) {
        isDataMismatch = true;
        break;
    }
  }

alert(isDataMismatch);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `var isDataMismatch = true;` should be `var isDataMismatch = false;` and visa versa within the part which breaks out from the `for` loop